# Display Flask JSON datas with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display json data coming from my flask function.

I can use getJson method to get those datas but getJSon work with action like click or change.

getJSon return data but i can't use use them out of the function.

For example

```
$.getJSON('../admin/graphe_1', {

}, function(data) {
    chart.data = data
    console.log(data)
}); 
console.log(chart.data)
```

The first console log display data but the second one display nothing.

How can I do to get this data out of the function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is `getJSON` function is asynchronous. So your second `console.log` prints the data before actually loaded into your app. So it prints null probably. The first `console.log` is in the function which executed right after completing loading data successfully. So it should print correct data. If you want to do stuff after loading data successfully do it in the done function which contains your first `console.log`. if you want synchronous execution use,

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  async: false,
  data: data,
  success: function (data){
      chart.data=data;
  }
});
console.log(chart.data); // data should be loaded
```

This is not recommend since it blocks UI thread.

Comment: It's a way to turn getJSON() function to synchronous ?? I can do it inside the done (right after the first console log) fonction of getJSON() for multiple reasons

Comment: Then use $.ajax directly with async flag to false. While this is not recommend way since it blocks the UI thread which might effect your responsiveness of UI. But if it fast loading you can apply.